# two for loop with two arrays and check if they match [half working]

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have this code, I use this code to print a map of teeth:

```
if($tip_dente == 2){
    for($i=0; $i<=7; $i++){
        for($j=0; $j<=$var_n; $j++){
            if($array_p1n[$i]==$array_denti_new[$j]){
            $pdf->Cell(0.5,1,$pdf->Image($array_p1[$i],$pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY(),0,1,'PNG'),1,C,1,false); // larghezza, altezza, txt, bordi, linea a capo, allineamento orizzontale, riempimento colore, ignorare
            $pdf->Cell(0.2,1,'',0,0,C,false);
        }else{
            $pdf->Cell(0.5,1,$pdf->Image($array_p1[$i],$pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY(),0,1,'PNG'),0,C,1,false); // larghezza, altezza, txt, bordi, linea a capo, allineamento orizzontale, riempimento colore, ignorare
            $pdf->Cell(0.2,1,'',0,0,C,false);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I use this code to browse the arrays and if they match the code prints an alternative image.
The code works indeed it prints an alternative image when the two arrays match but the problem is that it prints every tooth 4 times..
How can I fix this problem?

Using the function var_export I obtain this:

```
$array_p1n= array ( 0 => 18, 1 => 17, 2 => 16, 3 => 15, 4 => 14, 5 => 13, 6 => 12, 7 => 11, )
$array_denti_new= array ( 0 => '18', 1 => '17', 2 => '16', )
```

And it is ok because the first array is the one that I defined while the second array ($array_denti_new) is the array that I fill with elements took from the database. This is the array ($array_p1n) I created and it matches with the function var_export: `$array_p1n = array(18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11);`
With my code I would like to print the $array_p1n and while doing this I would like to check if the elements inside the second array ($array_denti_new) match with the elements of first array. If so, print an alternative image

Comment: So if an element `$array_p1n[$i]` presents in `$array_denti_new` array, it should do something. otherwise it should do something else, is it?

Comment: the $array_p1n[$i] is the array that I use (or at least I think it does) to print the teeth. When the elements (number) inside the $array_denti_new match with the elements inside $array_p1n[$i] it print an alternative image

Comment: Can you please provide sample data for $array_p1n and $array_denti_new that illustrate what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: an image? a grab/screenshots of the problem?

Comment: The result of `var_export($array_p1n);` and `var_export($array_denti_new);` [added to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34482360/edit) and an explaination what is supposed to happen based on that data would do nicely. Please pick significant data for the two arrays ;-)

Comment: using the function var_export I obtain this:
For $array_p1n=
array ( 0 => 18, 1 => 17, 2 => 16, 3 => 15, 4 => 14, 5 => 13, 6 => 12, 7 => 11, )
For $array_denti_new I obtain this:
array ( 0 => '18', 1 => '17', 2 => '16', )

And it is ok because the first array is the one that I defined while the second array ($array_denti_new) is the array that I fill with elements took from the database..

This is the array ($array_p1n) i created and it matches with the function var_export:

$array_p1n = array(18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11);

Comment: with my code I would like to print the $array_p1n and while doing this I would like to check if the elements inside the second array ($array_denti_new) match with the elements of first array. If so, print an alternative image

Comment: Info added to question...

Comment: Just to clarify: The code is supposed to add the same image but with a border when there is no corresponding element in denti_new and without an border if there is a corresponding element? And what is that `C` you use as the `ln` parameter?

Comment: If I have a match it add a border if not it doesn't add the border. The C is to center the element inside the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in_array()` function to check if an element exists in the array or not.

```
if($tip_dente == 2){
    for($i=0; $i<=7; $i++){
        if(in_array($array_p1n[$i], $array_denti_new)){
            $pdf->Cell(0.5,1,$pdf->Image($array_p1[$i],$pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY(),0,1,'PNG'),1,C,1,false); // larghezza, altezza, txt, bordi, linea a capo, allineamento orizzontale, riempimento colore, ignorare
            $pdf->Cell(0.2,1,'',0,0,C,false);
        }else{
            $pdf->Cell(0.5,1,$pdf->Image($array_p1[$i],$pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY(),0,1,'PNG'),0,C,1,false); // larghezza, altezza, txt, bordi, linea a capo, allineamento orizzontale, riempimento colore, ignorare
            $pdf->Cell(0.2,1,'',0,0,C,false);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the reference:

- [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem! I didn't know about the function in_array() it simplify my code a lot!